# UINavigationController custom transition animation view controller alpha value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, custom-transition

I want to make a transition, that in the end, the `ToViewController` alpha value will be something like 0.7, so the user still be able to see the `FromViewController`" at the background.

Why am I doing it? because at the end of transition I need to remove the `FromViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to take snapshot of the view controller at run time and navigate your desired controller with passing snapshot image and make it a background image of ToView Controller, so it will look like you are on a same page.

```
-(UIImage *)takeSnapshot:(UIView *)snapView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snapView.frame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [snapView drawViewHierarchyInRect:snapView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but I am pretty sure there is much simpler elegant one. I saw a tutorial for this, but can't find it anymore.

Comment: @RohitJha Use four tabs to indent codes. Please read the [tour] and answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.